# DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO seems to work in procedure but not in a job

Tags: oracle, plsql

The below sample code illustrates an issue I am having with dbms_application_info. If I use it in the below procedure:

```
create or replace procedure test01 is
vsql varchar2(50);
begin
vsql := 'select sysdate from dual';
execute immediate vsql;
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('TEST','Starting...');
dbms_lock.sleep ( 10 );
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(NULL, NULL);
end;
/

exec test01;
```

Then querying v$session reveals "Starting..." as I would hope!

However, it is necessary to run the related procedure in a job. If I do this, then I cannot see "Starting..."

```
declare 
JNAME varchar2(200) := to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHHMiSS');
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'TEST01_'||JNAME,
    job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action      => 'BEGIN TEST.TEST01; END;',
    start_date      => NULL,
    repeat_interval => NULL,
    enabled         => TRUE);
END;
/
```

This code should be executable by anyone who potentially wishes to have a look and perhaps help me understand why this would be?

Thank you! --> Scouse.

Comment: This procedure will raise an exception before any application info is set.

Comment: But it doesn't though... I'm running it. SQL> exec test01;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

Comment: Are you sure the job is running? Check with `SELECT JOB_NAME, STATE FROM ALL_SCHEDULER_JOBS;`

Comment: Yeah... the state changes to 'RUNNING'...

Comment: @Scouse_Bob Probably too late to suggest this but you’ll probably get more focussed answers without the `execute immediate`. A lot of people will expect that to fail (even though it actually doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `INTO clause` in your *execute immediate* statement

```
create or replace procedure test01 is
vsql varchar2(50);
l_date DATE;
begin
vsql := 'select sysdate from dual';
execute immediate vsql into l_date;  --<<<< here
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE('TEST','Starting...');
dbms_lock.sleep ( 20 );
DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(NULL, NULL);
end;
/
```

Using `INTO clause` both module and action are set.

As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317) if you ommit the `INTO clause` no exception is raised but

> If dynamic_sql_statement is a SELECT statement, and you omit both into_clause and bulk_collect_into_clause, then execute_immediate_statement never executes.

So I'd expect the application info should be set even without INTO clause, but from some reason it is not. Anyway using INTO it works fine.

I tested on 12.1

Comment: Hi, thanks for this -- The issue for me is that the procedure runs fine either run as a job, or run from just "exec test01;" however, if you run it as a job, then you do not get the entry in v$session that refers to it "running" as per the setting in dbms_application_info. It works one way, but not the other. This is my issue... :-/

Comment: The point is, what you want to achieve. If you want to have a meaningfull procedure - add the INTO clause and everithing works as expected.

Comment: If you want to understand, why you observe a strange behaviour by ommiting the `INTO clause` probably the best to explain is @StevenFeuerstein